# Trigger onPress event on Child component within Parent component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props

I made a button component which I render in my Parent component. Been stuck for a while now on trying to fire a function on the onPress event of this child component that is used in my Parent.

I've been looking through some of the recommended questions and answers but I need some specific advice.

I simplified my code as much as possible, please have a quick look.

Thanks in advance!

```
// PARENT COMPONENT
export class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
 }

onPress = () => {
   console.log("Hey");
};


render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <PrimaryButton text={"Sign up"} onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }
 }



// CHILD COMPONENT
const PrimaryButton = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={style.container} >
      <Text style={style.text}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default PrimaryButton;
```

Comment: `onPress` needs to get passed through to the button element.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific or implement in my code? I can't find the solution ...

Comment: I'm not sure what `<TouchableOpacity/>` is, but you should probably pass onPress to it.  `const PrimaryButton = ({ text, onPress }) => ...` and `<TouchableOpacity onClick={onPress}>`

Comment: My hero! Worked like a charm :) lots of thanks!

Comment: I'll add that as an answer so you can close the question!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `onPress` to `TouchableOpacity` as a prop. I don't know the props for `TouchableOpacity` but should be bound as either `onPress` or `onClick`. Event handlers always need to be passed to the root component (or as close to it as you can get, ie TouchableOpacity is from a 3rd party). Most, if not all, 3rd party components will have props for the proper events.

```
// CHILD COMPONENT
const PrimaryButton = ({ text, onPress }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={style.container} onClick={onPress} >
      <Text style={style.text}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```